# Replace any plain-text to class of specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

Trying to replace any plain-text like `[make-this-class]` to class like `<div class='make-this-class'></div>` of specific div `<div class='this-div-only'></div>`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='not-others-div'>
text text [make-this-class] text
</div>
Text text text
<div class='this-div-only'> <!-- this div only -->
text text [make-this-class] text
</div>
```

How to replace any plain-text [any-text] to a class of specific div of dom elements by jquery ?

Comment: You could remove the specific text node and replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try utilizing `.html()` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\[(.*)\]/`

```js
$(".this-div-only").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\[(.*)\]/, $("<div />", {"class":"$1"})[0].outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class='not-others-div'>
text text [make-this-class] text
</div>
Text text text
<div class='this-div-only'> <!-- this div only -->
text text [make-this-class] text
</div>
```

Comment: you are replacing the whole inner html, not the selected placeholder

Comment: Working, but others text or content become Deleted or removed. Please fix this.

Comment: regexp looks nice. i'm upvoting this.

Comment: @guest271314 Hi Serious problem: It replace only one [text], It should replace text to class all text of same dive, like: `[text1] ... [text2] ... [text3]` on same dive class. Please fix this.

Comment: @Aabira _"Serious problem: It replace only one [text], It should replace text to class all text of same dive, like: [text1] ... [text2] ... [text3] on same dive class. Please fix this."_ ? Not certain interpret comment correctly ? `[text1] ... [text2] ... [text3]` not appear at `html` at Question ? Tried adding `g` flag to `RegExp` ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 Hi thanks, but not understate. Please see this, i have asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32950651/4290783

Comment: @Aabira Does solution at post above resolve original Question ? , which did not include `[text1] ... [text2] ... [text3]` ?

Answer (score 0):

you store the content of your div, replace the string you're looking for and finally update your div's content with new content.

```
var content = $('.this-div-only').html();

var newcontent = content.replace('[make-this-class]', '<div class="make-this-class"></div>');

$('.this-div-only').html(newcontent);
```

Comment: thank, but how to replace any text like [any-text] to class of html node?

Comment: second statement replaces your placeholder... you want it to be dynamic? elaborate your question please.

Comment: i mean when i put any text inside [ ], like  [any text here] , text will be class of html node.

Comment: in this case, best solution would be using regular expressions to catch every patterns matching [ only alphabetical charachers and the dash sign ]. I suck at regexps, sorry :)