# Replace all plain-text to class of same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, replace

I have asked related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934862/replace-any-plain-text-to-class-of-specific-div).

Now trying to replace many *(more then one)* plain-text like `[make-this-class]` *to class like* `<div class='make-this-class'></div>` and  `[make-this-class2]` *to a class like* `<div class='make-this-class2'></div>` on same div `<div class='this-div-only'></div>`. 
Problem is given js replace only one single text, means its not replace others text of same div, when trying to replace text more then one it replace only one text of same div. Example HTML and JS given below.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='not-others-div'>
text text [make-this-class] text
</div>

Text text text

<div class='this-div-only'> <!-- this div only -->
text [make-this-class] text [make-this-class2] and [make-this-class3] and 10 text like this <!--trying to replace text more then one-->
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".this-div-only").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\[(.*)\]/, $("<div />", {"class":"$1"})[0].outerHTML)
})
```

So how to replace many text to a class (10 *ten text*) of same div of dom elements by jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `g` global flag in regex, and also you need to use `.*?` for matching the shortest

```js
$(".this-div-only").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, $("<div />", {
    "class": "$1"
  })[0].outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='this-div-only'>
  <div class='this-div-only'>
    <!-- this div only -->
    text [make-this-class] text [make-this-class2] and [make-this-class3] and 10 text like this
    <!--trying to replace text more then one-->
    text [make-this-class] text [make-this-class2] and [make-this-class3] and 10 text
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but is replace only two, not able to replace others 8 text (means i'm trying to replace 10 text on same dive) please fix it.

Comment: i have tried it to JSFiddle, but problem is it not give me the same result like Normal HTML web-page, means it getting different result on HTML web-page.

Comment: @Aabira : just add the html content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91399/discussion-between-aabira-and-pranav-c-balan).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding g (global), to change all ocurrences:

```
$(".this-div-only").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\[(.*)\]/g, $("<div />", {"class":"$1"})[0].outerHTML)
})
```

Pranav C Balan won me by 20 seconds

Comment: Hi, thanks, but is replace only two, not able to replace others 8 text (means i'm trying to replace 10 text on same dive) please fix it.